# PHP: Property visibilty, static, etc

Tags: php, oop

I know that this is a real stupid question, but I don't really understand something, I use them everyday, but I'm not sure how they work.

```
class Bootstrap
{
public static $frontController = null;
public static $root = '';
```

What's the diff between public static, protected, public...all of them? and when it's best to use each of one...

Best Regards

Comment: Can you make your title better? (More descriptive, also you don't need to tag it with PHP in the title since we have tags for that). ty :)

Comment: Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a good question for SO - the principles of OOP are much, much easier to learn systematically from a book (or an online article, of course.). The Wikipedia article gives an overview but it's hard to digest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `static` means the value is accessed via `self::$var` instead of `$this->var`, is not instance-specific (i.e. it's also available in static methods) and thus ideal for singletons and similar patterns
- a `public` var is accessible from everywhere, i.e. both from inside the class and outside
- a `protected` var is only accessible from inside the class and from classes inheriting from the class where the var is defined
- a `private` var is only accessible from inside the class

Since you are asking about OOP basics, here are some more keywords worth explaining:

- an `abstract` class cannot be instantiated but only used as a base class; a class containing abstract methods must be abstract and a class inheriting from an abstract class must be abstract unless all abstract methods of the base class are actually implemented
- a `final` class cannot be inherited from

Comment: If a declare a variable protected, I can't access it in a static method, only those are declared as static..or it has to be protected static?

Answer (score 1):

Public/private/protected refer to visibility;

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

static refers to whether a member of a class is associated with the class itself or an instance of a class;

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

These are all language keywords.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_%28computer_programming%29

Answer (score 1):

Public and protected are the visibility. Public everyone has access, protected only inherited and parent classes can access.

Static is a variable that is common to all objects, instead of each class have its own, it is "shared" by all objects.

Now to the other question, when to use it:

- All attributes should be private, to protect them from bad usage.
- All getter and setter methods should be public, so other objects can set and get the values.