# Is there any way I can change class variable, which would affect all instances created after?

Tags: php, oop

```
class foo
{
    public $bar = 1;    
}

#foo.bar = 2; //change class variable and affect all after

$a = new foo();
$a->bar = 2;//avoid DRY

$b = new foo();
$b->bar = 2;//avoid DRY

echo $a->bar;
echo $b->bar;
```

Is there any way I can change class variable, which would affect all instances created after?

I want to change one default value, but I don't want to keep repeating every time I instantiate a new object.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve but maybe you are looking for `$b = clone $a;`. Btw. you have to write `$` before variable even in class declaration. It should be `public $bar`.

Comment: using `static` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Property visibilty, static, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030981/php-property-visibilty-static-etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to make the variable static.

```
class foo
{
    public static $bar = 1; 
}

$a = new foo();
$a::$bar = 2;

$b = new foo();
echo $b::$bar; // 2
```

You can also do `Foo::$bar = 2;` to set the variable for all instances.

Comment: do i must start $a = new foo(); first?

can I do it without start any new

Comment: @BenjaminW of course not, it's a static variable, you can pretty much do `Foo::$bar = 2;`. I created the `$a` and `$b` variables to follow your code.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that it affects all objects, existing ones as well as newly created.

Comment: @NigelRen that's what he wants I guess when he said `I don't want to keep repeat every time I start a new object`, no?

Answer (score 1):

Having a static property works great if the constructor should be called each time. If you're attempting to chain invocations, however, you might use `clone` instead.

```
class Foo
{
    public $bar = 1;

    public function bar(?int $bar = null): Foo
    {
        $this->bar = $bar ?? $this->bar;

        return $this;
    }

    public function copy(?int $bar = null): Foo
    {
        return $this->fork()->bar($bar ?? $this->bar);
    }

    public function fork(): Foo
    {
        return clone $this;
    }
}

$a = new foo();

$a2 = $a->copy();
$b = $a->copy(2);
$b2 = $a->copy();
$c = $b->copy(3);
$c2 = $b->copy();
```

https://3v4l.org/Fevli

Note, there is also a `__clone()` magic method that allows you to configure the actual cloned properties that go along (e.g., reset or increment, etc).

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I think what the OP is really after is a static `Foo::withProperty()` initializer that sets the property based on class configuration. Static properties work in some scenarios (but not all), the above works for downstreaming mutations, `with()` methods create consistently configured representations, which is what the OP seems to want in practice.

Comment: I indeed maybe should've suggested a static setter function rather than a property. Oh well, I suppose it's fine x)

Answer (score 0):

Here's method using `static::with()` methodology, which might fit best for the DRY approach of preconfiguration.

```
class Foo
{
    public const DEFAULT_BAR = 5;

    public $bar = FOO::DEFAULT_BAR;

    public function bar(?int $bar = null): Foo
    {
        $this->bar = $bar ?? $this->bar;

        return $this;
    }

    static public function withBar(?int $bar = null): Foo
    {
        return (new self())->bar($bar ?? Foo::DEFAULT_BAR);
    }

    public function fromBar(?int $bar = null): Foo
    {
        return (new self())->bar($bar ?? $this->bar);
    }

    public function fork(): Foo
    {
        return clone $this;
    }
}

$a = Foo::withBar();
$b = Foo::withBar(4);
$b2 = $b->fromBar();
$c = Foo::withBar();
```

https://3v4l.org/qI8SY